# requests.exceptions.HTTPError vs requests.HTTPError

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there any reason to prioritize raising/catching `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` over `requests.HTTPError` or `requests.HTTPError` over `requests.exceptions.HTTPError`?

These two are the same class (As can be seen by reading the source code and by witnessing `True` is the output of `requests.exceptions.HTTPError is requests.HTTPError`), yet I ask this question as they both exist.

Comment: Both are a reference to the same class. There's no difference.

Answer (score 2):

They both do the same thing. There's no reason to prioritize one over the other.

Try this experiment:

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/nothere')
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.response.text)
```

And then:

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/nothere')
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.response.text)
```

You'll get the same thing each time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    [***]
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/nothere</code> was not found on this server.  
  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```